# How to access HDD connected to Apple AirPort Extreme router while connect to my home OpenVPN Server

Tags: networking, vpn, wireless-router, openvpn, raspberry-pi

I basically have a HDD connected to my Apple AirPort Extreme router via USB. When I am on my home network I can access this HDD. I have set up a OpenVPN server at home that I can connect to from anywhere but I cant find how to connect to the HDD connected to my router through my OpenVPN server.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you are connected you can access any other subnet within that network. So when I connect to OpenVPN I get a IP address of 192.168.200.X with my home network on the subnet 192.168.1.X

So all I need to do is access 192.168.1.X and then can access any device on that network as well.